# invariant violation element type is invalid expected a string

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Greeting ... Today i have create new project for ReactNAtive...And try to perform the Drawer example ... it show me this error which i have specify in the title...
here is my code ... please help to solve this error...

1) Create Project using react-native init hworld
2) npm for 
npm install --save react-navigation
npm install --save native-base
npm install --save react-native-drawer

MY INDEX.JS FILE CODE

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';


AppRegistry.registerComponent('hworld', () => App);
```

3) created New Folder 'hw' and File AppContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import  {Navigator}  from 'react-navigation';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

export default class AppContainer extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      toggled: false,
      store: {},
      theme: null
    }
  }
  toggleDrawer() {
    this.state.toggled ? this._drawer.close() : this._drawer.open()
  }
  openDrawer() {
    this.setState({toggled: true})
  }
  closeDrawer() {
    this.setState({toggled: false})
  }
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch(route) {
      default: {
        return null
      }
    }
  }
  configureScene(route, routeStack) {
    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => this._drawer = ref}
        type="displace"
        content={<View style={{backgroundColor: "#000", height: 1000}}/>}
        onClose={this.closeDrawer.bind(this)}
        onOpen={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}
        openDrawerOffset={0.2}
        >
          <Navigator
            ref={(ref) => this._navigator = ref}
            configureScene={this.configureScene.bind(this)}
            renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
            />
        </Drawer>
    )
  }
  /*render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>

      </View>
    );
  }*/
}
```

4) App.js file Code

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import AppContainer from './hw/AppContainer';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
     <AppContainer/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: At which line does the error occures ?

Comment: INSIDE THE RETURN...RENDER()....AppContainer.JS File

Comment: If you specify the line number it would be easier to find a solution :)

Comment: render() {
    return (
      <Drawer

Comment: plz check the import React, { Component } from 'react'
//import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer'
import { View,Drawer } from 'react-native'
import  {Navigator}  from 'react-navigation' ...This is prefect... ????